# How do i restart a console game?

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and i started with c#. So i followed a tutorial on making a simple game in console. [Here's the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1c7PYHhmow). And when i finished the tutorial i was left with a decent game but it wasnt polished. The game doesn't restart itself.

I've tried some different ways trying to get around it but nothing i tried seemed to work (because im new and half the coding didnt make sense).

So i tried this. why doesn't this work?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DodgeGame
{

public class Game
{
    //This is our constructor,
    // it gets run auto when new instance is made.
    public Game()
    {
        //PLAYER
        playerUnit = new PlayerUnit(5, 5, "@");

        //ENEMY
        enemyUnits = new Unit[ numEnemies ];

        Random = new Random();
        Score = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < numEnemies; i++)
            {
                int row = Random.Next(0, Console.WindowHeight - 1);
                enemyUnits[i] = new EnemyUnit(Console.WindowWidth -1, row , "<");
            }

        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    }



    private Stopwatch stopwatch;

    private Unit playerUnit;

    private int numEnemies = 20;
    private Unit[] enemyUnits;

    public static Random Random;
    public static int Score;

    public void Run()
    {

        stopwatch.Start();
        long timeAtPreviousFrame = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;


        while(true)
        {
            //Time since last frame.
            int deltaTimeMS = (int)(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
                                    - timeAtPreviousFrame);
            timeAtPreviousFrame = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;


            //Updating Units.
            playerUnit.Update(deltaTimeMS);

            for(int i = 0; i < enemyUnits.Length; i++)
            {
                enemyUnits[i].Update(deltaTimeMS);

                if( playerUnit.IsCollidingWith(enemyUnits[i]))
                {
                    //Then game over.
                    GameOver();
                    return;
                }
            }
            playerUnit.Draw();

            foreach (Unit u in enemyUnits)
            {
                u.Draw();
            }


            //Draw the score.
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.WindowHeight - 1);
            Console.Write("SCORE: " + Score.ToString() );

            //Lets just do a tiny sleep to avoid running at too high of fps.
            Thread.Sleep( 5 );

        }

        //PROGRAM END.
    }

    void GameOver()
        {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Game Over. Your Score was: " + Score);
        Console.WriteLine("Insert Name to LeaderBoard:");
        //TODO: Make a local leaderboard?

        if(Console.KeyAvailable == true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            while(cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                if(cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar) Game();
                cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            }


        Console.SetCursorPosition(0,Console.WindowHeight - 1);


        }

}
```

}

I want to restart my game without closing the window.

Sorry if this isnt enough info to help.

Comment: this is not the part of the information you should be providing, its not enough.

Comment: Yeah the main thing would be, to show how the main function looks like and what happens during the game loop (we could ofcourse check the tutorial, but that would mean that your question doesn't contain enough information)

Comment: well, this proves how much i dont know :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have main function/calling function as follows;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var game=new Game();
    //May be some initialization logic       
    game.Run();
}
```

In that you can add a while loop and check for user input, if he wants to exit then he can press specified key (Esc maybe...)

Refer following code;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
        var game = new Game();
        //May be some initialization logic       
        game.Run();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to restart, press Esc to close.");
        var userInput = Console.ReadKey();
        if (userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
             return;
    }
}
```

You could tweak this logic as per your need but I think you'll get my point.

Comment: thanks a flippin tonne. well explained n all. exactly what i wanted :)

Comment: I have another question if u dont mind. How do i remove my arrow keys (use them to move my character in game) from this statement. so if i die and i immediately press an arrow key the game will restart without me knowing my score. sorry in advance if im newb

Comment: Add `Console.ReadLine();` as last line in `GameOver()` method. That will show the Score until you press Enter. And after pressing Enter you will get message regarding restart or close.

Comment: the way i did it was i added a while loop. which basically said if i press UpArrow ConsoleWrite "anyother key". but then i ran into another bug regarding that if the UpArrow if statement was ontop of the LeftArrow if statement. then if i hit my LeftArrow first it would skip over the Up if statement. so at the end of all the if's i put continue; which seemed to restart the if instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop. Check if the user wants to exit or start the game (for example with ESC and Space) and then handle it appropriately.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
while(cki.Key != KeyCode.Esc)
{
     if(cki.Key == KeyCode.Space) Game();
     cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work, its probably not a flaw in your code but im not using it right. could u briefly explain it?

Comment: Maybe tell me what part doesnt work? Roughly explained it loops through the code and keeps reading a key until you press the escape key.

Comment: Ok, well im not sure that's what im looking for im not sure. can i make it so that when i press the SpaceBar it will just 'reset' and go back to the start of "Game"?

Comment: WAIT! it seems to work! i messed around abit not sure if this is the cleanest coding but i did "Game game = new Game(); game.Run();"

Comment: Ah, if you worked with instances it should also work with your way :) Good job on finding the solution!

Answer (score -2):

what is in Game(). you can use new instance.

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

exit from current process.
        envoinment.exit();

Comment: *I want to restart my game without closing the window.*
have u read qustion above ?

Comment: Downvote reason: Why not keeping the process alive instead of creating a new one and killing the current process? Seems like unnecessary overhead to me, that makes the application much more complicated than it should.